# Initializer.Seed() throws exception on context.SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm relatively new to EntityFramework (started using it today!)

I have the following code:

```
    public class DemoContext : DbContext
    {
        public DemoContext() : base("demoContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<BaseUser> Users {get; set;}
        public DbSet<BaseSession> Sessions {get;set;} 
     }

    public class DemoInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DemoContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DemoContext context)
        {
            var staffUsers = new List<StaffUser>
            {
                new StaffUser {Id=1,Username="test",Password="test",DisplayName="test user",AccessFlags=(AccessFlags)2048 },
            };

            staffUsers.ForEach(su => context.Users.Add(su));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

But whenever the `context.SaveChanges();` line is called, it throws the following exception:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error retrieving values from ObjectStateEntry.
>   See inner exception for details.

And the inner exception is:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Whilst this error doesn't really mean much to me at this point, and Googling around hasn't produced any answers,  I have seemingly managed to nail it down to being related to the public property `DbSet<BaseSession> Sessions {get;set}` on the DemoContext class
(By this I mean, if I comment it out, the error doesn't occur and away we go!)

Why is this, and what's the correct fix?

Do I need to do something with all of the DbSet properties present in a DbContext if I use Initializer.Seed()?
*I'm assuming you don't actually have to populate them all with data, as that doesn't make sense?*

.
Screenshot of the full exception, incase it's useful!
[image: Screenshot of the full exception, incase it's useful!]

.
**EDIT**

I've dialed it down to being a problem with this specific implementation of the `BaseSession` class:

```
public class UniqueSession : BaseSession
{
     public Date DateOfSession { get; set; }
     public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Which, as you can see, uses a custom `Date` class, which I pilfered from another question on here:

```
    public class Date : IEquatable<Date>, IEquatable<DateTime>
    {
        public Date(DateTime date)
        {
            value = new DateTime(date.Date.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
            //value = date.Date;
        }

        public bool Equals(Date other)
        {
            return other != null && value.Equals(other.value);
        }

        public bool Equals(DateTime other)
        {
            return value.Equals(other);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
        public static implicit operator DateTime(Date date)
        {
            return date.value;
        }
        public static explicit operator Date(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return new Date(dateTime);
        }

        private DateTime value;
    }
```

If I switch `UniqueSession.DateOfSession` to be a `DateTime`, this error doesn't occur?

.
**EDIT 2**
If I change the `Date` class so that the `private DateTime value;` is actually a public property (`public DateTime value { get; set; }`), the error goes away!

But why?

Comment: Are you sure about that commenting-out of the Sessions set? Try it a few times.

Comment: 100% sure that commenting the line out makes everything fine and dandy.

Comment: Can you post the User, StaffUser and Session classes, at least how they relate to each other?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I've updated my question as I've got a little further. Seems to be relating to a custom class used as the type for one of the inheriting classes?

Comment: Also, BaseUser is an abstract class, which StaffUser implements. BaseSession (nor any derived types) has no relation to either BaseUser or StaffUser

Comment: That custom Date class should be automatically treated as a complex type, so I still don't see the problem.

Comment: that is exactly my thinking... *puzzled*

Comment: this type has no parameterless contructor, may be ?

Comment: @tschmit007 - Added one on your suggestion, but get the same results.

Comment: any user property related to your Date type (last connection date, last session, current session... or the same)?

Comment: Found what precisely is causing the error, and updated the question accordingly, but if you can tell me WHY, that would be ace!

Comment: because before you did not have property in you complextype class, so nothing to "materialize" in the db, you should have a protected modifier for the set I think.

Comment: @tschmit007 I suppose that makes sense.. feel free to stick that as the answer, and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complex type is (beyond other) a shortcut to "create columns in the database".

One column for one public property of the class. With no property in the class there is no column to map/create.

This may confuse EF.

Answer (score 1):

The class Date for EF is like any other not built in (and handled by EF) type.
 So:
- the DateOfSession is a reference to Date
- Date (Dates) is a table on SQL Server (and a DbSet on the context)

In this case the EF probably is looking for the DbSet<Date>